# visual studio web test error handling

Tags: visual-studio, testing, error-handling, load

I'm using Visual Studio Ultimate 2013 and have a load test that uses a web test with a number of request and web test plugins.

In my PostRequest plugin, I'm checking the http status code of the response and am flagging an error in a WebTest.Context parameter, when a hhtp code of over 400 is returned. What I want to do is pick this up in the PostTransaction WebTest plugin and update a database table. The problem is, that the test aborts when the framework detects the error and the PostTransaction plugin isn't called.

I've added a PostWebTest plugin, that I thought would be called when the test iteration aborted, but it's never hitting this when a request fails. It does hit it if the test is successful. What am I missing?

```
public override void PostRequest(object sender, PostRequestEventArgs e)
{
    ...
    statusCode = e.Response.StatusCode.GetHashCode();
    If (statusCode > 400)
    {
        e.WebTest.Context["TransactionFailCount"] = 1;
    }
}

public override void PostTransaction(object sender, PostTransactionEventArgs e)
{
    int transactionFailCount = Convert.ToInt32(e.WebTest.Context["TransactionFailCount"]);
    if (transactionFailCount > 0)
        failCount = 1;
    else
        passCount = 1;
    ...
    base.PostTransaction(sender, e);

 }

 public override void PostWebTest(object sender, PostWebTestEventArgs e)
 {
     base.PostWebTest(sender, e);
 }
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

A Web Performance Test (WPT) will continue to execute after an error is detected unless the `Stop on error` property of the test is `true`. It is possible that some aspects of a the handling of a request are not performed after an error, but I have not seen any such cases.

Be careful of terminology. WPTs use "transactions" as a way of grouping several requests. The context (right click) menu of a request has an "Add transaction" entry that selects a range of items in the test to be included in that transaction. Perhaps you should be using the `PostRequest` or `PostPage` plugins rather than `PostTransaction`.

I recommend that you do some experiments with a simple two or three request WPT plus some simple plugins that just announce that they have been called. For example

```
public override void PostRequest(object sender, PostRequestEventArgs e)
{
    e.WebTest.AddCommentToResult("PostRequest called for url " + e.Request.Url);
}
```

Additionally, there is a good explanation of how and when plugins are called in pages 32 to 44 of the [Visual Studio Performance Testing Quick Reference Guide](http://vsptqrg.codeplex.com/) from Codeplex.

The statement `statusCode = e.Response.StatusCode.GetHashCode();` is strange. The value of `e.Response.StatusCode` is an `enum`, it integer value can be obtained by casting. The `GetHashCode` method is not intended to get the numeric value of an `enum`. The statement would be better as `statusCode = (int)e.Response.StatusCode;` or the assign and test (note that `if` is used for conditionals in C#, not `If`) might be better as

```
statusCode = e.Response.StatusCode;
if ( e.Response.StatusCode >= System.Net.HttpStatusCode.BadRequest ) { ... }
```

Comment: Thanks Adrian. The "If" was simply a typo in the post and I inherited the code for obtaining the status code. I've corrected it now you're rightly pointed it out. I'll certainly turn off the "Stop on Error" and handle it in my code.

Comment: Please read the [help] page on what it means when as answer is accepted, see http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer . If your question has not been answered then please edit it to explain the missing details.